# How to get correct row data from jquery dataTable after column sorting?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using jquery dataTable for displaying customer records.  First time i go to customer page,i have 20 customer records in dataTable sorted by 
customerId column( so they are diplayed starting from 20 to 1  where 20 is the id of 20th customer and 1 is the id of first customer) in desc
order. 20th customer is shown at top in dataTable.

now if do below in my javascript code

```
 var customerTable=$('#customer').dataTable();// where customer is the html div associated with dataTable

 var custData = customerTable.fnGetData(18)// it gives me data of 19 row in dataTable( as dataTable index starts from 0)
 // so i get the data of customer having customer id=19
```

**Perfectly fine till here.**

Now i click the sorting icon on  customerId column . So after sorting customer with id as 1 is displayed on top in dataTable and customer with id as 20
  will be displayed at bottom. Now i do the my javascript operation again

```
var customerTable=$('#customer').dataTable();

 var custData = customerTable.fnGetData(18)
 // it should give me data for customer id=2 Right? but still i am getting the old data i.e customer Data having id=19.
```

**Why i am not getting the right data after sorting? how should i get the correct data with row id after dataTable
     sorting?**

Comment: You may check out this discussion in datatables.net - http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/13315/fngetdata-does-not-return-the-data-in-right-order-after-column-sorting-in-jquery-datatable#Item_6

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing with little change.

First created global variable to hold the table.

```
var customerTable;
```

Then initiated the object in onready state.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        customerTable = $('#customer').dataTable();
});
```

If you sort and get the data now. You probably get what you want.

```
var custData = customerTable.fnGetData(18);
```

Only thing I aware of is I didn't initiate the table object after sorting.

Comment: i am already doing it this way where i have created customerTable as global variable but the issue still persist.

Comment: Strange. This works on me very well. I think you will require to do more debug to catch in which stage the change happen.